# Can't add bounty on 2 day old question

Tags: support, bounty

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/not-all-categories-being-displayed) is 2 days old, yet there is no link to add a bounty.  I am logged in, and I have 68 rep points.

Answer (score 2):

You need [more rep: 75](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

When you go top the box under your name, you’ll find a link named *privileges*:

[image]

There, you get to the overview of most privileges and the required reputation.